# Fluid simulation don't work

Tags: fluid-simulation

I set everything up correctly (I compared it on YouTube), but the particles do not appear. I attach the file (I brought everything related to the simulation to a separate collection). I would be grateful if someone answers.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Il5ISmUZ-f1-vounSpEx7oApbUYCpKsq/view?usp=sharing

Comment: to add to Chris' answer, after applying rotation and scale of the 2 objects (domain and inflow), and after recalculating the inflow normals, you can increase the Liquid > Sampling value of the domain up to 5 for example, your inflow object is probably too small for the moment. Then Cache > Type > Press on Replay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*** UPDATE ***

Thanks for updating your file.

You can see the "resolution box" in the edge of the domain. Just try to change the resolution, then it should be visible.

Still your resolution is too small.

And also your "opening is too small". I made your hole a bit bigger and turned up the resolution to 300, then i started seeing water:

[image]

[image]

---

well...your first sentence of your question is pretty self confident...but honestly i have to say: i can't believe that. You made the "typical" beginner mistakes - which we all made - me not, i made them 10 times. ;)

First, you have to make sure that in your models the face orientation is right. Blue means: it's ok. Red means: inside (normally means wrong because you cannot look inside of objects - yes, there are exceptions...).

you can check your face orientation here by checking "face orientation":

[image]

you repair face orientation by clicking a red object, press TAB, press A, then SHIFT-N. Then tab again. Your object should now turn blue.

Next beginner mistake: you should have applied scale and rotation in simulations, else the simulation will go pretty wrong or weird or won't work at all. (your scales were sometimes even negative...)

If you apply scale and rotation, your transform panel looks like this:

[image]

Scale is 1, rotation is 0.

To do that, select your object, press CTRL-A, and choose Rotation & Scale.

Now to your resolution in your domain and your inflow:

This symbol on your domain object:

[image]

shows your minimal "water pixel". So if your inflow object is smaller than that - nothing will happen. You should make that "water pixel" so little that it fits a few times in your inflow object.

after changing all this, and your simulation still won't work, please upload your "repaired" file again.

Comment: I was just browsing, and had no idea what that little thing meant. Thanks for the random good advice, stranger.

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the scale and rotation angle (and rotated the edges to be blue), but it didn't work. As I understand it, in order to change the size of the "water pixel" (which is not visible in the output, please tell me how to show it) you need to change the resolution to higher values, but the simulation does not start. Here is the modified file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mInt4pvlpNCq8WjVbo8Ea9WjXhuHY1bm/view?usp=sharing